# Why is /dev/rfcomm0 giving PySerial problems?

Tags: python, application-development, bluetooth

I am connecting my Ubuntu box to a wireless readout setup over Bluetooth. I wrote a Python script to send the serial information through /dev/rfcomm0. The script connects fine and works for a few minutes, but then Python will start using 100% CPU and the messages stop flowing through.

I can open rfcomm0 in a serial terminal and communicate through it by hand just fine. When I open it through a terminal it seems to work indefinitely. Also, I can swap the Bluetooth receiver for a USB cable, and change the port to /dev/ttyUSB0, and I don't get any problems over time.

It seems either I'm doing something wrong with rfcomm0 or PySerial doesn't handle it well.

Here's the script:

```
import psutil
import serial
import string
import time

sampleTime = 1
numSamples = 5
lastTemp = 0

TEMP_CHAR = 't'
USAGE_CHAR = 'u'
SENSOR_NAME = 'TC0D'

gauges = serial.Serial()
gauges.port = '/dev/rfcomm0'
gauges.baudrate = 9600
gauges.parity = 'N'
gauges.writeTimeout = 0
gauges.open()

print("Connected to " + gauges.portstr)

filename = '/sys/bus/platform/devices/applesmc.768/temp2_input'

def parseSensorsOutputLinux(output):
    return int(round(float(output) / 1000))

while(1):
    usage = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=sampleTime)
    gauges.write(USAGE_CHAR)
    gauges.write(chr(int(usage))) #write the first byte
    #print("Wrote usage: " + str(int(usage)))

    sensorFile = open(filename)
    temp = parseSensorsOutputLinux(sensorFile.read())
    gauges.write(TEMP_CHAR)
    gauges.write(chr(temp))
    #print("Wrote temp: " + str(temp))
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

EDIT: Here is the revised code, using Python-BlueZ instead of PySerial:

```
import psutil
import serial
import string
import time
import bluetooth

sampleTime = 1
numSamples = 5
lastTemp = 0

TEMP_CHAR = 't'
USAGE_CHAR = 'u'
SENSOR_NAME = 'TC0D'

#gauges = serial.Serial()
#gauges.port = '/dev/rfcomm0'
#gauges.baudrate = 9600
#gauges.parity = 'N'
#gauges.writeTimeout = 0
#gauges.open()

gaugeSocket = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
gaugeSocket.connect(('00:06:66:42:22:96', 1))

filename = '/sys/bus/platform/devices/applesmc.768/temp2_input'

def parseSensorsOutputLinux(output):
    return int(round(float(output) / 1000))

while(1):
    usage = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=sampleTime)
    #gauges.write(USAGE_CHAR)
    gaugeSocket.send(USAGE_CHAR)
    #gauges.write(chr(int(usage))) #write the first byte
    gaugeSocket.send(chr(int(usage)))
    #print("Wrote usage: " + str(int(usage)))

    sensorFile = open(filename)
    temp = parseSensorsOutputLinux(sensorFile.read())
    #gauges.write(TEMP_CHAR)
    gaugeSocket.send(TEMP_CHAR)
    #gauges.write(chr(temp))
    gaugeSocket.send(chr(temp))
    #print("Wrote temp: " + str(temp))
```

It seems either Ubuntu must be closing /dev/rfcomm0 after a certain time or my Bluetooth receiver is messing things up. Even when the BluetoothError arises, the "connected" light on the receiver stays illuminated, and it is not until I power-cycle to receiver that I can reconnect.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. It's odd that the connection would work fine for a few minutes (seemingly a random amount of time) and then seize up.

In case it helps, the Bluetooth receiver is a [BlueSmirf Silver](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10269) from Sparkfun. Do I need to be trying to maintain the connection from the receiver end or something?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but have you considered using a `BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)` from the `python-bluez` library and treat it like the network protocol it is, rather than going through a virtual `/dev/rfcommX` serial device?  I found the socket interface a bit more reliable when I was last dealing with an RFCOMM based protocol, and it removes the need for root access to configure the serial device ahead of time.  There is some sample code here: http://homepages.ius.edu/rwisman/C490/html/PythonandBluetooth.htm

Comment: Using python-bluez allows the connection to persist indefinitely. Perhaps it was a problem with Bluetooth timing out... I'd still be interested in figuring out the Serial problems, though. EDIT: Actually, the connection still fails after a few minutes. Python doesn't hog the CPU, though. Here's the error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gauges-daemon.py", line 49, in <module>
    gaugeSocket.send(TEMP_CHAR)
  File "<string>", line 5, in send
bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (11, 'Resource temporarily unavailable')`

Comment: Perhaps this error condition is sending pyserial into a tight loop.  You might have some luck running the program under `python -mtrace -t program.py` and see if you can trigger the error.  This produces a lot of output, so you'd probably want to redirect `stderr` to a log file.

Comment: I don't think there's a tight loop problem. Here's a few snippets from the mtrace output: Normally, `--- modulename: bluez, funcname: send
<string>(2):  <string>(3):  gauges-daemon.py(51):  gaugeSocket.send(chr(temp))
 --- modulename: bluez, funcname: send
<string>(2):  <string>(3):  gauges-daemon.py(39):  usage = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=sampleTime)` , whereas on the very last call before failure, `--- modulename: bluez, funcname: send
<string>(2):  <string>(3):  <string>(4):  <string>(5):   --- modulename: trace, funcname: _unsettrace
trace.py(80):         sys.settrace(None)`

Comment: I was thinking more about your PySerial version: that's the one you said was eating 100% CPU.  I'd expect the traceback would give enough information about the problem in the socket version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the Bluetooth buffer on the PC was overflowing because I was never calling recv() in the Python script.

The Bluetooth accessory was sending characters to the PC, which the script ignored and which inevitably led to a buffer overflow. This overflow apparently causes the rfcomm channel to lock up until the buffer is read.

Here is the working script, for future reference:

```
import psutil
import serial
import string
import time
import bluetooth

sampleTime = 1
numSamples = 5
lastTemp = 0

TEMP_CHAR = 't'
USAGE_CHAR = 'u'
SENSOR_NAME = 'TC0D'

filename = '/sys/bus/platform/devices/applesmc.768/temp2_input'


def parseSensorsOutputLinux(output):
    return int(round(float(output) / 1000))

def connect():
    while(True):    
        try:
            gaugeSocket = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
            gaugeSocket.connect(('00:06:66:42:22:96', 1))
            break;
        except bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError as error:
            gaugeSocket.close()
            print "Could not connect: ", error, "; Retrying in 10s..."
            time.sleep(10)
    return gaugeSocket;

gaugeSocket = connect()
while(True):
    usage = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=sampleTime)
    sensorFile = open(filename)
    temp = parseSensorsOutputLinux(sensorFile.read())
    try:
        gaugeSocket.send(USAGE_CHAR)
        gaugeSocket.send(chr(int(usage)))
        #print("Wrote usage: " + str(int(usage)))

        gaugeSocket.send(TEMP_CHAR)
        gaugeSocket.send(chr(temp))
        print gaugeSocket.recv(1024)
        #print("Wrote temp: " + str(temp))
    except bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError as error:
        print "Caught BluetoothError: ", error
        time.sleep(5)
        gaugeSocket = connect()
        pass

gaugeSocket.close()
```

The key change is in the addition of the line

```
gaugeSocket.recv(1024)
```

which cleans the buffer of the "okay" messages sent back from the remote device.