# Python PyBluez loses Bluetooth connection after a while

Tags: python, bluetooth

I am using Python to write a simple serial Bluetooth script that sends information about my computer stats periodically. The receiving device is a [Sparkfun BlueSmirf Silver](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10269).

The problem is that, after the script runs for a few minutes, it stops sending packets to the receiver and fails with the error:

```
(11, 'Resource temporarily unavailable')
```

Noticing that this inevitably happens, I added some code to automatically try to reopen the connection. However, then I get:

```
Could not connect:  (16, 'Device or resource busy')
```

Am I doing something wrong with the connection? Do I need to occasionally reopen the socket? I'm not sure how to recover from this type of error.

I understand that sometimes the port will be busy and a write operation is deferred to avoid blocking other processes, but I wouldn't expect the connection to fail so regularly. Any thoughts?

Here is the script:

```
import psutil
import serial
import string
import time
import bluetooth

sampleTime = 1
numSamples = 5
lastTemp = 0

TEMP_CHAR = 't'
USAGE_CHAR = 'u'
SENSOR_NAME = 'TC0D'

filename = '/sys/bus/platform/devices/applesmc.768/temp2_input'


def parseSensorsOutputLinux(output):
    return int(round(float(output) / 1000))

def connect():
    while(True):    
        try:
            gaugeSocket = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
            gaugeSocket.connect(('00:06:66:42:22:96', 1))
            break;
        except bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError as error:
            print "Could not connect: ", error, "; Retrying in 5s..."
            time.sleep(5)
    return gaugeSocket;

gaugeSocket = connect()
while(1):
    usage = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=sampleTime)
    sensorFile = open(filename)
    temp = parseSensorsOutputLinux(sensorFile.read())
    try:
        gaugeSocket.send(USAGE_CHAR)
        gaugeSocket.send(chr(int(usage)))
        #print("Wrote usage: " + str(int(usage)))

        gaugeSocket.send(TEMP_CHAR)
        gaugeSocket.send(chr(temp))
        #print("Wrote temp: " + str(temp))
    except bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError as error:
        print "Caught BluetoothError: ", error
        time.sleep(5)
        gaugeSocket = connect()
        pass

gaugeSocket.close()
```

EDIT: I should add that this code connects fine after I power-cycle the receiver and start the script. However, it fails after the first exception until I restart the receiver.

P.S. This is related to my recent question, [Why is /dev/rfcomm0 giving PySerial problems?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114171/why-is-dev-rfcomm0-giving-pyserial-problems), but that was more about PySerial specifically with rfcomm0. Here I am asking about general rfcomm etiquette.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is the same as the answer to [Why is /dev/rfcomm0 giving PySerial problems?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114171/why-is-dev-rfcomm0-giving-pyserial-problems), a simple issue of the Bluetooth buffer overflowing on the PC.